# Remove blue color and green color of an image

Tags: swift, image, ciimage, colorfilter

Please help me to remove blue color and green color of an image in Swift. This is my custom kernel string (to remove the red color in image):

```
func createCustomKernel() -> CIColorKernel {
        let kernelString =
            "kernel vec4 chromaKey( __sample s) { \n" +
                "  vec4 newPixel = s.rgba;" +
                "  newPixel[0] = 0.0;" +
                "  newPixel[2] = newPixel[2] / 2.0;" +
                "  return newPixel;\n" +
        "}"
        return CIColorKernel(string: kernelString)!
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'll adjust my answer, but you question title asks about removing BG while your code supposedly removes R only. (I say supposedly because I'm not sure what it *really* does.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to remove RGB base values, why not make your kernel this?

```
kernel vec4 chromaKey( __sample s) {
    return vec4(s.r, 0.0, 0.0, s.a);
}
```

If you wish to *gradually* remove the `g1 and`b values, let me know. Takes a bit more coding, but easily done.